# Displaying an image file stored on mongodb

Tags: mongodb, image

I found a convenient way in my app to save small uploaded image files (png or jpeg) to the mongodb without third party resources. The resulting documents look like this:

```
{ 
"_id" : "QuX8YaKmWfmBcEv", "type" : "image/png", 
"creator" : "83BEoeKvtYLTcKQtc", 
"data" : BinData(0,"iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABAAAAAQCAIAAACQkWg2AAAABGdBTUEAAK/INwWK6QAAABl0RVh0U29mdHdhcmUAQWRvYmUgSW1hZ2VSZWFkeXHJZTwAAAAsSURBVHjaYvz//z8DKYCJgUTAAqE+RjESVMq/7D85NoxqGCkaGGmeWgECDAAufgkbzM8Q4AAAAABJRU5ErkAABl0RVh0U29mdHdhcmUAQWRvYmUgSW1hZ2VSZWFkeXHJZTwAAAAsSURBVHjaYvz//z8DKYCJgUTAAqE+RjESVMq/7D85NoxqGCkaGGmeWgE.... and so on ....") 
}
```

Now, I'm trying to display these images though javascript, but nothing I do seems to get the image displayed. Here's an example of code I've tried:

```
var imageFile = Images.findOne({_id: imageId})
var imageBlob = new Blob([imageFile.file], {
                type: imageFile.type
            });
var img = new Image();
img.src = URL.createObjectURL(imageBlob);
$("#contents").html('<img src="'+img.src+'">)
```

The result is a standard "missing image" icon.

The weird thing is: I'm storing/retrieving/playing audio files in the same app, but can't seem to get these images working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, it turned out to be an easy solution:

```
var imageFile = Images.findOne({_id: imageId})
var imageBlob = new Blob([new Uint8Array(imageFile.data)]);
var img = new Image();
img.src = URL.createObjectURL(imageBlob);
$("#contents").html('<img src="'+img.src+'">)
```